# Function(arguments): Correcting the order of input

Tags: javascript, function, class

This isn't a code issue, more of a general question.

When you include `(arguments)` in functions, or object / constructor methods, the order in which they are passed into the function is important.

example: `function(x,y,z) != function (z,y,x)` and would give a different result/might cause bugs depending how the variables are passed.

Is there something I can write inside the function to correct the order of the values to what the function expects?

So that it doesn't matter if `function(z,y,x)` or `function(y,x,z)` are passed, because function always correct itself to `function(x,y,z)`

Or is this an aspect of good programming where you want everything to be explicitly defined, & absolute, so you don't have to set up contingencies in the way I described.

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: Types (TypeScript if you like) surely help,. Functions with (ideally) only one argument are even better. When you need more then accept an object and use its properties. Surely I wouldn't write a function that somehow guess how to "correct" its inputs

Comment: The position of arguments is important, yes. That's a fundamental fact. How would you magically "correct" `f(3, 4)` to `f(4, 3)`?! How do you decide what the caller *meant*? Why can't the caller do what they *mean* in the first place?

Comment: @hifilo I'd like to add: the question itself isn't inherently _bad_. It's simply (at least how it's currently phrased) off-topic for SO. Different languages have different constructs/features to avoid the kind of bugs you're worrying about (but it's never - AFAIK - resolved by the called function alone). Prototypes like `foo(int, bool, bool, bool)` aren't that uncommon (unfortunately). Plus: on the top of everything else: tests...

Comment: This just reminds me of https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/charles_babbage_141832.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Yes exactly. I'm not as experienced with programming so this is an XY question. Apologies for that. I wasn't sure if this is something that would be done. Creating a method similar to an "auto-correct" inside the function would probably require an unnecessary amount of engineering, and to me didn't make sense, but I wasn't sure.

These answers have helped clear things up for me.

Comment: Sounds like you want to implement basic argument validation inside of your function.

Comment: @epascarello Yes exactly, I wasn't sure if this was a programming concept. Thank you!

Comment: FYI: some languages, like [tag:python], support *named arguments*, like `foo(bar=42, baz=True)`. This allows you to pass arguments in arbitrary order, but it's still the caller that needs to associate the right names with the right values. The object solution given below somewhat emulates this in Javascript. Though in no language is it sensible to just throw values in random order at a function and expect the function to sort it out itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a function like

```js
function f(x,y,z) {
  return x + 2*y + 3*z
}
```

the input is ordered, so a call `f(1,2,3)` binds `x=1, y=2, z=3` locally inside the function scope (`{}` braces).
To input arguments without explicit order, there needs to be some kind of way to identify the argument without position, this can be achieved by mapping each argument with a name in an object and passing it to the function.

```js
function g(obj) {
  { z, x, y } = obj
  return x + 2*y + 3*z
}
```

This way the input is order free, but the information about what argument belongs where is still encoded.

Making `f(1,2,3)`, `g({z:3,y:2,x:1})` and `g({x:1,y:2,z:3})` give the same result.

Comment: Thanks. So I'm clear, for this to work, the object has to be defined outside of the function's scope before being passed in?

Comment: Yes, something like `const obj = {z:3,y:2,x:1}`